# What happens to registeredReceiver when app is killed on Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to monitor network connection changes. (I know how to do it)
I did not use manifest file as I don't want my closed app to be awakened for connectivity changes. So, I register my custom BroadcastReceiver within my main application object (not in activity).

If I did that in my activity, I could unregister it onStop or onDestroy.

As I don't do this in activities, what happens when app is terminated (forceably by the system or killed cleanly by user with pressing back button (for eg.)? (I won't know when the app is terminated so I can't unregister it manually.. Should i?)

Will registered receiver still work? Will the app get awakened? Will it be cleaned completely and safely?

Answer (score 0):

You should unregister it onStop and onDestroy.
That would take care of all your use-cases.

Since you are using the Receiver dynamically in your activity, and not from the manifest, it will only receive the intent if the Receiver has been registered.

So if you register onResume and unregister onStop and onDestroy, it will only receive intents as long as your activity is visible to the user in the foreground and at no other time.